# JAVA-Spring : How to create beans in a loop?

Tags: java, spring

I am new in spring and have to use spring annotations all through the project. I need to create a list of beans. I do not have option to use context.getBean("..") from the class where I have to create the list.

**The problem is :**
I have 3 classes: Processor, Reader, Writer. I have to create a list of writers inside the processor class.

**This is what I am looking for : ( trying to @Autowire 'RoxourReader readerThread' and  'List writerThreads'  but don't know how determine the size of the list and need to add the name as well)**

```
package company.online.Roxour.api.operation;
{

@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class RoxourProcessor
{

    .........

    private int PAYLOAD_SIZE;

    private int  MAX_READER_THREADS;
    private int  MAX_WORKER_THREADS;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationEnvironment applicationEnvironment;

    @Autowired
    RoxourUtil util;

    //I wish to have something like this
    @Autowired 
    RoxourReader readerThread

    //I wish to have something like this
    @Autowired
    List<RoxourWriter> writerThreads;



    @PostConstruct public void initialize()
    {
        PAYLOAD_SIZE = applicationEnvironment.getPayloadSize();
        MAX_READER_THREADS = applicationEnvironment.getMaxReaderThreads();
        MAX_WORKER_THREADS = applicationEnvironment.getMaxWorkerThreads();
    }

    ..............

}

}
```

Reader class looks like :

```
package company.online.Roxour.api.operation;
{

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class RoxourReader extends Thread
{

    .........


    @Autowired
    ApplicationEnvironment applicationEnvironment;


    public RoxourReader( String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    ..............

}


}
```

And the writer class looks like :

```
package company.online.Roxour.api.operation;
{

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class RoxourWriter extends Thread
{

    .........


    @Autowired
    ApplicationEnvironment applicationEnvironment;


    public RoxourWriter( String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    ..............

}

}
```

context.xml has:

```
 <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="company.online.Roxour.api"/>
```

According to current implementation, this is the way we are creating the treads:

```
private void createAllThreads()
{

    readerThread = new RoxourReader(  "Reader " + 1 );


    writerThreads= new RoxourWriter[ MAX_WORKER_THREADS ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_WORKER_THREADS; i++ )
    {
        writerThreads[ i ] = new RoxourWriter( "Uploader " + i);
    }

}
```

Is this possible? Please advise me a different approach with annotations otherwise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a IoC framework like Spring, you leave the task of bean creation to Spring. So you shouldn't use new keyword, this is made by Spring automatically.

Instead you should get your beans through context.getBean("beanname") or
 injecting the bean with @autowired.

Here there is an example or Spring with threads (There is 3 good examples)
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-and-java-thread-example/

And here there is the definition of task executors.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Answer (score 0):

To begin with,

```
public class RoxourReader extends Thread
{
```

is not a good idea, because you are not extending the Thread behavior. Instead make it

```
public class RoxourReader implements Runnable
{
```

and when you use the keyword `new` to create an object, then Spring is not actually managing it.

So change the lines

```
new RoxourReader... &
new RoxourWriter
```

to Autowired (or) getBeans methods like

```
private void createAllThreads()
{

    readerThread = getReaderBean("readerBeanName");


    writerThreads= new Runnable[MAX_WORKER_THREADS];

    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_WORKER_THREADS; i++ )
    {
        writerThreads[ i ] = getWriterBean("Uploader " + i);
    }

}
```

And your getBeans methods would look like,

```
public Runnable getReaderBean(){
       Runnable obj= applicationContext.getBean("RoxourReader");
       return obj;
}


public Runnable getWriterBean(){
       Runnable obj= applicationContext.getBean("RoxourWriter");
       return obj;
}
```

Since your scope is `Prototype` for both reader and writer beans already, you will get a new bean instance.

Comment: Probably best as a comment.

Comment: @Makoto, I was still editing the answer. Do you still think it is good as a comment?